# Zend Form Element Number

Tags: html, zend-framework, zend-form

I am new to zend framework. I was wondering whether any zend form element for number. I need to convert the below html stuff to zend form.

```
<input type="number" name="min" id="min" min="0" max="45" value="0" size="2" step="5" maxlength="2"/>
```

How can I convert the above html code to zend form?

Thanks.

**Update**

I have searched in the internet and found some resources

[link](https://zf2-doc-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.element.number.html)

But I didn't understand the usage.

```
        $test=new Zend_Form_Element_Number('test');
```

Does the above usage is correct?  I am getting the below error while using the above code

> Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Form_Element_Number' not found

(I am getting down votes, that is why I updated this)

Comment: which version of zendframework are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you have given it seems you are using ZF 1.x. But the link you have given is for ZF 2.x. [HTML5](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.elements.html#html5-elements) Elements elements are available only from ZF 2.0